How to change the color of the black bar at the bottom of the MAUI app screen?
I'm developing an application on maui, I've already searched a bunch of files, but I can't find how to change the color in the navigation bar area. Please help me, I don't understand how to fix it.
I've tried changing colors in almost all style files. I also change the style for the TabLayout, if I apply margin, then the edges also remain black. Changing the background for the elements does not give any results

Please try to add some code as well in the question so that other devs can review your code and suggest some solutions.

From top to bottom, the colors are controlled by: StatusBar community toolkit behavior, Shell.BackgroundColor, Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor. If your case is more specific - add your XAML.

@H.A.H. It didn't work

On Android, you can use method Window.SetNavigationBarColor to achieve this. We can just add code Window.SetNavigationBarColor to file MainActivity.cs of android platform.
Please refer to the following code:
 public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
 {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        //Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Orange);
        Window.SetNavigationBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);


        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
 }

